# Software Updates for my program in Java

Tags: java, deployment

I'm working on an application in Java for a client, and I'm having some doubts about how to distribute it. I have read about Java Web Start, and have some questions:

- Should it be valid for updating my app if I install it and launch from the start menu?
- Could I run my java application offline?

Do you know another alternative rather than WebStart for deploy and update?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry if is a duplicate post, I've been digging in SO for a couple of days and I haven't found an answer yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your first question, the user will always see that latest version of your application, even if they are using a Start Menu entry.  This is stated clearly in the FAQ; see the answer to [Q5](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#105).

In answer to your second question, yes an application can be run offline, provided that it has already been cached.  This is mentioned in the FAQ answer to [Q25](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#225).  For more details, refer to the documentation of the [`information`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#information) element of the JNLP file; specifically look for the section on "offline-allowed" and what it means.

I'd recommend that you read the material on Oracle's [Java Web Start](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/index.html) web page to understand what JWS can (and can't) do.

Answer (score 1):

["Getdown"](http://code.google.com/p/getdown/)

for more info read similar article in this forum
["stackoverflow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254328/java-web-start-alternative)